# How to add this google play update dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, google-play, updates

Recently I saw this update dialog of Google Play integrated right within the app of Swiggy. This method allows you to keep the user stay on your app and update rather than jumping around the Google Play Store to update it.

So what happens is that you click the update button within your app and boom this dialog appears which handles everything like downloading installing and then it restarts the app. So you actually never leave the app.

I have tried searching a lot but no clue of what this is even called. 
You can watch this screenshot of that dialog which appears.

https://ibb.co/HGDSN7M

https://ibb.co/BLCKmnx

Comment: It is called [in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new feature that was just announced by Google at Google I/O 2019. You can [read about it here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates). It is called In-app Updates.